# In bUnit how can I wait for OnAfterRenderAsync() in the page that is my RenderComponent to complete?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, bunit

Blazor server, .NET 8 (pre-release), I have a bUnit test where I need to wait for the OnAfterRenderAsync() in the page I am testing to complete before running tests.

So I need something like:

```
var renderedComponent = ctx.RenderComponent<LouisHowe.web.Pages.Account.ConfirmPhone>();
renderedComponent.WaitForRenderToComplete();
```

Is there a way to test for this? The best I have come up with is set a value in a hidden element in the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` and WaitFor that element to have that value. I don't like populating elements solely for testing, but that would work.

**Update:** Why do I need this? Because I have two pages where I have a `@ref=` to a child component. And I access that to complete the initialization of the page.

I also have a page that needs to call JavaScript to get some browser settings to complete the initialization of a page.

So in those two cases, I'm not able to test everything having been initialized on the page until `OnAfterRenderAsync()` completes.

Comment: It depends on what you want to test - obviously in `OnAfterRenderAsync` the renderer doesn't produce new markup, unless you call `StateHasChanged`.

Is there any observable state change? Maybe on the next render cycle if you would change an input argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions might be either misleading or there is a misunderstanding.
If you are in `OnAfterRenderAsnyc` - there will be no more render-cycles (hence the name of the function). Only exception: You call `StateHasChanged` inside.

So I am not sure if you want to wait **until** `OnAfterRendererAsync` gets called or if you really want to await that call somehow. I will try to answer both.

### Wait until `OnAfterRenderAsync` gets called

You can leverage the behavior of the Blazor renderer itself. That is, as long as you have synchronous code, `RenderComponent` will return to the test code right before `OnAfterRenderAsync` is called.

Now, synchronous code would also be achievable as long as you have async code that is directly completed.

So if you have something like this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   bar = await Repository.GetByIdAsync(id);
}
```

And in your test you do something like that:

```cs
var repositoryMock = CreateRepositoryMockOrFake();
Repository.GetByIdAsync(1).Returns(Task.FromResult(new Bar());
```

You still run synchronously! With that, `RenderComponent` will be synchronous! So once `RenderComponent` returns - the `OnAfterRenderAsync` function is called.

### Wait until `OnAfterRenderAsync` is finished

Now that part is trickier! The method isn't called `OnAfterRenderAsync` without a reason. So without any further information, it is hard to tell what to do.

1. You could use `WaitForState` and look for an internal observable state

```cs
var cut = RenderComponent<Foo>();

// Bar will be set to 10 inside OnAfterRenderAsync
cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Instance.Bar == 10);
```

2. There is observable DOM change
   If you have something like `StateHasChanged` inside your `OnAfterRenderAsync` obviously you can just observe that state from the outside, as you would with any other button click or whatnot.
3. There is no direct observable state change
   If there is nothing you can directly observe, well it might be worth **not** testing it all! It seems like an implementation detail and should be left alone.

The exception to this is, of course, if you "not observable state change" has effects on render cycles / events what not afterward. If so, trigger those actions.

Comment: You answered my question - thank you. With that said, I don't understand what is going on in the first part. What is the `Repository` variable and what is the `CreateRepositoryMockOrFake()` method doing? TIA

Comment: If you have any service that, in your production code, is producing asynchronous code, then you should mock out this behavior so it becomes "synchronous" in your test code. The way to do that is that you return completed tasks (with your expected result as payload).